# Adding to Nested Array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Suppose I had three arrays nested in a document as follows and I knew all the indices. How would I add another element to the third array, in this case "array3"? I wouldn't be able to use the positional operator but is there a way to update/push when you know the indices?

```
"name1": "foo1",
"array1": [
      {
        name2: "foo2",
        "array2" : [
          {
            "name3" : "foo3",
            "array3": [
              {
                data : "ImData"
              }
            ]
          }

        ]

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I figured it out. I somehow missed just directly referencing it via its index. I figured it possible but just about every example showed positional references and I couldn't find the syntax to do it directly. It's quite simple. To add to array 3 above when knowing the index you'd:

```
db.collection('productlist').update({name1:'foo1'},{'$push': { "array1.0.array2.0.array3": {"data": "yay"}}}
```